# Custom HTTP handler not working in .NET

Tags: .net, sharepoint, httphandler

I have created a custom HTTP handler for all the pdf files and it works perfectly fine if I directly access pdf files.

However if the same PDF page is getting called from some other asp page custom http handler for pdf is not getting invoked.

Is there any setting which we need to do in IIS7 so that all the requests to pdf files will go through the custom handler ?

Comment: What does "PDF page is getting called from some other asp page" mean?

Comment: Please share some code. Do not use comment, but edit your question (in order to paste formatted code). And if you use SharePoint, please add the corresponding tag, and state it explicitly that in the question, as SharePoint adds a lot of features over asp.net.

Comment: There are two ways of calling a pdf . You can directly access the pdf page e.g. http://localhost/abc.pdf or it can be called from a asp page e.g http://localhost/download.aspx?abc.pdf. Handler is working fine in first case but it is not working in the second case

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add some code and some configuration section.

Comment: I have added the code in the question

Comment: @user2452067 - "localhost/download.aspx?abc.pdf" does not mean anything for anybody except you. What does `download.aspx` code-behind do to invoke the PDF handler?

Comment: Ok.. so how do I call my custom handler from download.aspx page. Also the download.aspx page will also make a request for a pdf in that case handler should be invoked right ?

Comment: Again, I don't know what is meant by "download.aspx page will also make a request for a pdf". You need to explain your intentions and show your code that is not working to your expectaions.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is very unclear to understand what you are trying to do, please note that SharePoint provide this feature **out-of-the-box**.

For example, if you PDF is located at :

```
http://yourserver/documents/somedocument.pdf
```

You can get a forced download of the file using:

```
http://youserver/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/documents/somedocument.pdf
```

Comment: That's where the problem is.. If I directly use http://yourserver/documents/somedocument.pdf my custom http handler is getting invoked. But when I use http://youserver/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/documents/somedocument.pdf http handler is not getting invoked